# Different behavior on <pre><code>

Tags: html, css

I am using google prettify to highlight code on my website. To be HTML 5 conform I use:

```
<pre class="prettyprint"><code class="language-java"></code></pre>
```

To modify the used font and size I added to my css:

```
code { font: normal 400 1.2rem/1.5 'Roboto Mono', monospace; }
```

I tested it with IE-Edge and Firefox and all was fine. Later I have seen, that Chrome was accepting the font(-family) but not the size (bigger than expected). While IE and Firefox inherited the the size from `<html>` as expected.

Meanwhile I made a small workaround and additionaly added:

```
pre { font: normal 400 1.2rem/1.5 'Roboto Mono', monospace; }
```

Using `<pre>` alone is no option, because then IE and Firefox don't accept the font(-family), while Chrome does, but now he makes the size smaller than expected.

That IE often has different behavior than other browsers is known, but in this case Chrome acts differently. Is the redundant code used in `pre`and `code`the only "solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`<pre>` and `<code>` are both part of the HTML 5 spec. There is no need to use both.</strike> Sorry, misunderstood your intention.

For font-related problems, it's a bit complicated, see [this article.](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/fixing-browsers-broken-monospace-font-handling/)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Maybe I should additionaly say, that I use the line `font: normal 400 62.5%/1.5 Roboto, sans-serif;` in my `<html>` tag, and all other values are `rem` based. So I expect 12px (1.2rem) based on 16px, which seems to be the case currently.

Comment: Now that I've read the article, I understand the root of my problem.

Comment: @Martin Please try to use CSS reset: http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/ . There is no absolute font size specified in your HTML file. The `62.5%` merely tell the browser to use whatever font size their default (built-in) stylesheet specifies (usually 16px but not consistent), then multiply it by 62.5%.